# Settings.bundle for standalone watch app?

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos, settings.bundle

I am looking for a settings.bundle for the standalone watch app. In Xcode you can create a Settings.bundle but it seems like this isn't working for a standalone watch app, only for ios apps. Is someone familiar with a similar solution so that I can configure the settings outside the app. thanks

Comment: It seems there is no standalone watch app settings.bundle

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650383

The referenced wwdc2020 did also not provide any solution. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10171/